# Not able to fix datatable issue using php

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

Hi i am trying to use datatable plugin on my table which is populating using mysql query result data.But i am getting following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined
```

Please check my code below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo_page.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo_table.css">



<table class="table table-striped well dataTable" id="courseslist">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th>Course ID</th>
                    <th>Course Title</th>
                    <th>Course Desc</th>
                    <th>Course Year</th>
                    <th>Course Start Date</th>
                    <th>Course End Date</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                    <td>63495</td>
                    <td>Course C</td>
                    <td>Course C</td>
                    <td>2013</td>
                    <td>14-Oct-2013</td>
                    <td>18-Oct-2013</td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-courseid="63495" data-coursetitle="Course C" data-coursedesc="Course C" data-year="2013" data-startdate="2013-10-14" data-enddate="2013-10-18" href="#editcoursemodal" id="editcoursebutton" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-white icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-courseid="63495" href="#deletecoursemodal" id="deletecoursebutton" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-white icon-remove"></i> Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                    <td>66247</td>
                    <td>Course A</td>
                    <td>Course A</td>
                    <td>2013</td>
                    <td>30-Sep-2013</td>
                    <td>04-Oct-2013</td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-courseid="66247" data-coursetitle="Course A" data-coursedesc="Course A" data-year="2013" data-startdate="2013-09-30" data-enddate="2013-10-04" href="#editcoursemodal" id="editcoursebutton" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-white icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-courseid="66247" href="#deletecoursemodal" id="deletecoursebutton" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-white icon-remove"></i> Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                    <td>86714</td>
                    <td>Course E</td>
                    <td>Course E</td>
                    <td>2013</td>
                    <td>28-Oct-2013</td>
                    <td>01-Nov-2013</td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-courseid="86714" data-coursetitle="Course E" data-coursedesc="Course E" data-year="2013" data-startdate="2013-10-28" data-enddate="2013-11-01" href="#editcoursemodal" id="editcoursebutton" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-white icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-courseid="86714" href="#deletecoursemodal" id="deletecoursebutton" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-white icon-remove"></i> Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                    <td>90013</td>
                    <td>Course B</td>
                    <td>Course B</td>
                    <td>2013</td>
                    <td>07-Oct-2013</td>
                    <td>11-Oct-2013</td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-courseid="90013" data-coursetitle="Course B" data-coursedesc="Course B" data-year="2013" data-startdate="2013-10-07" data-enddate="2013-10-11" href="#editcoursemodal" id="editcoursebutton" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-white icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-courseid="90013" href="#deletecoursemodal" id="deletecoursebutton" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-white icon-remove"></i> Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                    <td>96599</td>
                    <td>Course D</td>
                    <td>Course D</td>
                    <td>2013</td>
                    <td>21-Oct-2013</td>
                    <td>25-Oct-2013</td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-courseid="96599" data-coursetitle="Course D" data-coursedesc="Course D" data-year="2013" data-startdate="2013-10-21" data-enddate="2013-10-25" href="#editcoursemodal" id="editcoursebutton" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-white icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-courseid="96599" href="#deletecoursemodal" id="deletecoursebutton" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-white icon-remove"></i> Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                                 </tbody></table>
```

After this i am calling js files in js section like below.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(event) {

$('#classeslist').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
      null
    ]
});
});
```

i tried with `"aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]]` also not working.

Comment: Where are you seeing the error?

Comment: i am getting in the log. I just used $('#classeslist').dataTable(); in other two pages it worked perfectly

Comment: I don't understand the problem. AFAIK you're receiving a js error `Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined` of some object. What object? Where is the error? I am not entirely clear as to your problem

Comment: I am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined

Comment: Which log? Webserver? MySQL? Your custom logging? Something else?

Comment: The error message seems js related, but apart from that, no one can deduce the problem as the code you have provided thus far is not at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your table id and your call to datatables don't match.

Make it

```
   $('#courseslist').dataTable({
```

not #classeslist, and it should work.